# Comparing times in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, if-statement, python-datetime

I've no idea what I'm doing wrong in the following line of code and it's driving me nuts!
As you'll probably know from the code, I only want the ***if block*** to run if it's before 5.15pm.

```
if time(datetime.now().hour,datetime.now().minute) < time(17, 15):
```

I've imported `date` and `datetime` so that's not the issue (it's `TypeError` error - see below error message I'm getting)

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: _run_module_as_main) 'module' object is not callable
```

Can someone advise on what I'm doing wrong

Comment: If you're just doing straight-up `import time` then obviously `time(17, 15)` or `time(anything)` would fail since you're just calling the module itself. You'd have to do `from time import time` or `time.time(whatever)`. But without a [mre] of your code that's just a complete guess. You have a decent amount of rep on this site so I'm surprised you'd omit it.

Comment: you can also compare them as numbers ```datetime.now().hour*100+datetime.now().minute < 1715```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to [`from datetime import time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects):

```py
from datetime import datetime, time

now = datetime.now()

if time(now.hour, now.minute) < time(20, 15):
    print("Hello")
```

Prints (now):

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

a bit shorter:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

datetime.now().time() < time(20,10)  # False
```

Comment: So simple in the end... Thanks!